# Why does Xcode keep asking me for the keychain password?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

I'm currently working with Mac the first time, building an iOS app. It works for a colleague, but not for me.

When I go to **Product > Archive** (Any iOS Device (arm64)), it starts working. I can hear the fan go crazy. Then it stops and asks me for a password. The message is in German:

> German Original: codesign möchte auf den Schlüssel "Apple Development: [My name]" in deinem Schlüsselbund zugreifen. Um dies zu erlauben, gib das Passwort für den Schlüsselbund "Anmeldung" ein.

> Translated: codesign wants to access the key "Apple Development: [My name]" in your key chain. To allow this, enter the password for the key chain "Login".

When I enter the wrong password, the window shakes. When I enter the correct password, the window closes and immediately asks me for exactly the same password. I tried entering the correct password for 10 times - I assume entering it more often does not change the outcome.

Why does Xcode keep asking me for the password?

### What I've tried

- Opening the Keychain access app and changing the keys settings to allow any program access. Didn't help.

I have Xcode 13 and macOS Big Sur 11.6.

Comment: Make sure you check the option to don't ask again or remember your decision or whatever it says (I can't recall exactly, but I think it is the button on the left of the dialog)

Comment: I tried. Still it showed up again.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't know exactly what did the trick, but I guess three things: (1) Your hint (2) Marking the certificate so that every program can use it (3) restarting everything.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I proposed to close my question as a duplicate of this one yesterday. So yes, it did :-)

Comment: @DanielWiddis Thank you for the hint - I didn't notice the infobox before. I've accepted it :-)